# Is there a way to color code events in de default Calender application

Tags: 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-s, calendar

I am using the (I think default) **Calender** application on my Samsung Galaxy S phone.

It shows blue blocks for my events in the 7 day view.

Is there a way to **change this blue color** ? So that, e.g. I can mark private events in green and appointments with customers in red ?

Or is there a way to **show some text in the blocks** ?

Or it not possible with the default calender .. do you know of another one which does allow this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can, you will need to create a different "calendar" (probably "tag" would be a better name, but that's Google's terms for it).

Creating a Calendar (do this from the Desktop, I didn't found a way to do it from Android's Calendar app; do anyone know?):

1. Go to http://www.google.com/calendar.
2. Look for the "My calendars" box on the left, click on "Add"
3. Fill in the information, and click Create Calendar.
4. You can change the color later from "My calendars" box, by clicking on the triangular button.

[image: Creating a Calendar]

Adding Events to Calendar (can be done from Android):

1. On the "Create New Event" view, choose the calendar you've just made from "Calendar" combobox.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: +1 for taking the time to anwswer my question - but, still, it's not exactly what I am looking for, I think. I want to add color to different events in the same calendar. Following your sugguestion, forces me to create google accounts for each type of event I want to enter : personal, customer, holiday, family things - I want to see them all in my own diary, but color codes.

Comment: @Edelcom: You can create multiple calendars in a single Google account (that's why I think they are better named "tags" or "groups" or "folders" rather than "calendars").

Comment: I do exactly what Lie says.  I put birthday events in one calendar, etc.

Comment: Ok, I have to change my way of thinking here ... but even than: that's for the Google calender, can you do the same on the local calendar of the device ?

Comment: @Edelcom: Try this: `Press Menu > More > My calendars > Menu again > Add calendar`; I can't tell if it works, as in my case the "Add calendar" button is greyed out, it might work in yours or it might not.

Comment: To sum up -- for one google account, a "calendar" represents a tag, if you will.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: I don't even have an 'Add Calendar' . See my response to the other answer from "pydave" where I list all options I see on my phone. I upgrade to 2.2 last weekend, but still am not able to add a Calendar on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

After following Lie's steps to create a new calendar in Google Calendar, you'll have to add it to the Calendar app:

1. Open the Calendar app
2. Menu > My Calendars
3. Menu > Add calendars
4. Select the calendar you just added

---

Lie mentioned this in a comment, but I don't have enough rep to respond.

**Add calendar** is for adding calendars to the app that aren't in the **My calendars** list already. It won't let you add new calendars to Google Calendar.

(The above is true on my xt720 running eclair-2.1.)

Comment: Sorry, my version (2.2) does not have a 'Menu > My Calendars' option, just Search, Create , Goto , Today, Delete, More and More having Refresh and Settings . Settings having, Calendars, Calendar sync, Default view ... all view settings and Vibrate . Calendars just a way to enable one of three calendars, My calendar, the online google one and the one from Facebook, pressing menu here only shows 'Calendar sync'. Am I missing an option ?

Comment: @Edelcom: Are you using the stock calendar application? The stock calendar app have a completely different set of menus. Either you have downloaded an alternative Calendar or Galaxy S ships its own calendar app; can other Samsung Galaxy S owner confirm this? btw, your question tag said you're using 2.1-eclair, but now you're saying you're using 2.2, have you upgraded since then?

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Yes I upgrade my Galaxy S during the weekend. I a running Calender 1.1 - no about settings anywhere to be found. The Application list just shows version 1.1.

Comment: @Edelcom: Application info shows my Calendar app is version 7 (on eclair). Your "Calendar" must be quite different from my "Calendar".